# How to you set a area with defined borders that functions as a link?

Tags: html, hyperlink

What I'm trying to do is set a radius within an image in HTML using px where that radius functions as a link. Basically, creating a portion of the image that functions as a link, while the rest doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for image maps.

Example:

```
<img src="workplace.jpg" alt="Workplace" usemap="#workmap">

<map name="workmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="34,44,270,350" alt="Computer" href="computer.htm">    
  <area shape="rect" coords="290,172,333,250" alt="Phone" href="phone.htm">
  <area shape="circle" coords="337,300,44" alt="Coffee" href="coffee.htm">
</map>
```

Taken verbatim from https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_imagemap.asp